# Consultas en MYSQL

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, sql

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuál sería la consulta adecuada para esto?

Listar el autor del libro más caro

```
SELECT MAX(PrecioCompra) from libros (select idAutor from Autoreslibros);
```

Intenté eso

Listar el autor del libro más barato

```
SELECT MIN(PrecioCompra) from libros (select idAutor from Autoreslibros);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tus consultas me parecen con buen inicio pero incompletas en su estructura ya que por ejemplo te faltaría hacer un agrupamiento, tu subconsulta no tiene alguna condición para que se establezca una condición de selección con base en lo que deseas; entonces se me ocurre:

- Para la consulta del libro mas caro observamos que tienes una relación de muchos a muchos
- Entonces elegimos al nombre del autor de la tabla `Autores`
- De la tabla `Libros` elegimos el máximo precio con dicha función de agregación
- Hacemos un `INNER JOIN` entre la tabla `Autores` y la tabla `pivote`
- Hacemos un `INNER JOIN` entre la tabla `Libros` y la tabla `pivote`
- Agrupamos por el nombre del autor
- Ordenamos de forma descendente por la columna calculada que le dimos un alias de `Caro` para obtener al inicio los registros mas caros
- Para dejar solo al autor con el libro mas caro, hacemos un `LIMIT 1`

CONSULTA:

```
SELECT Autores.Nombre,
       MAX(Libros.PrecioCompra) AS Caro
FROM Autores
INNER JOIN AutoresLibros ON Autores.idAutor = AutoresLibros.idAutor
INNER JOIN Libros ON Libros.idLibro = AutoresLibros.idLibro
GROUP BY Autores.Nombre
ORDER BY Caro DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Bajo ese mismo orden de ideas, para listar al autor ahora con el libro mas barato podrías:

- Usar esta misma consulta pero con la función de agregación `MIN`
- Dejar esta misma consulta pero en el ordenamiento en lugar de utilizar `DESC` lo hacemos de forma `ASC` para obtener los registros de menor precio al inicio del conjunto de resultados

Comment: Gracias, me sirvió del todo, me arrojó el resultado que debería...